# Disable/Enable Input when checkbox is clicked jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm attempted to only allow the submit button in a form to be enabled when a user has checked off a checkbox. I've gotten the button to start disabled, then become enabled when the checkbox is initially clicked on, but if I then uncheck the checkbox, the button doesn't become re-enabled.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="waivercheck">
<input class="submit join-button" type="submit" value="Join Now" id="joinevent" disabled>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#waivercheck').click(function(){
        if($(this).checked){
            $('#joinevent').prop("disabled",false);   
        } else {
            $('#joinevent').prop("disabled",true);
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the checkbox status via `this.checked` and not `$(this).checked`. And I recommend using the `change` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#waivercheck').change(function(){        
        if(this.checked){
            $('#joinevent').prop("disabled",false);   
        } else {
            $('#joinevent').prop("disabled",true);
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/rbnndz23/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the conditional.

A jQuery object doesn't have a `checked` property but the DOM element itself does

Instead of

```
if($(this).checked)
```

Can do

```
// native element has checked property
if(this.checked)
```

Or

```
// jQuery is() with pseudo selector
if($(this).is(':checked'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$(this).checked`. Instead try using `this.checked`. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xwuava84/).